# woocommerce-products-header in Subcategory - Remove Header Image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have searched around but can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for. I have subcategories set up on my store, and images assigned to these subcategories, as I want the thumbnails to be displayed when you click into a main category [image: Sub Categories Layout].

However, when I then click into the subcategory page, to display products within that subcategory, the image I set for the thumbnail appears under the description, quite large.

I don't want the subcategory image on the product list page whatsoever. Is there anything within the woocommerce code I can change or add to make this happen? This is what it looks like now... [image: This] I want it to look like this [image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using CSS, you can just remove the photo with `{ display:none; }`.  Post the HTML for that image using a web inspector and I'll give you the proper selector.

Comment: Ah! Perfect that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: What CSS did you use to hide the image?

Comment: I used the "woocommerce-layout.css" file, and changed `code`img{height:auto;max-width:100%;}`code` to `code`img{height:auto;max-width:100%;display:none;}`code`

Comment: that didn't remove all of your images?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia No! Just the one I wanted removing (the large category image)

Answer (score 0):

**Using functions.php:**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'custom_subcategory_thumbnail', 10 );
function custom_subcategory_thumbnail( $category ) {
    if ( $category->parent == '0' ) {
        woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $category );
    } else {
        // do not show a category image
    }
}
```

**Using CSS:**

```
.tax-product_cat ul.products li.product a img {
  display:none
}
```

Note: this code was found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-subcategory-images/).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, that just gets rid of the subcategory thumbnails on the main category page which I want to keep! I want to remove the large image from the subcategory "landing page" which displays the products. I had already seen that answer from that link